# A Less Offensive Word For Crippled Beggar?

Tags: word-choice, euphemisms, political-correctness

What would be a nice way of saying a crippled beggar?

For example I want to say "I gave some money to a crippled beggar who was begging on the road" but the word *crippled* and *beggar* doesn't seem nice (I want to write this down on a journal kind of place).

Any suggestions on how to put this more nicely?

PS:- By the way I don't need the wording to be very formal or anything. What I meant by "journal" was to mean something like a "diary". Sorry if it confused you.

Comment: I gave some money to alleviate the dire straits of a physically-challenged brother-in-alms.

Comment: A mobility-limited supplicant? Unless this is an historical piece, why the need for this archaic characterization?

Comment: "an infirm drifter"

Comment: @bib If you are asking why I have said "crippled beggar" I think its because my vocabulary is not very good. That's why I'm asking for better words :)

Comment: @Can'tTell differently-abled panhandler

Comment: Being a crippled beggar is not nice. Why would you want to have a "nice" expression for it? I call it reality; the alternative is hiding the truth.

Comment: The point is to say it in a non-offensive way- i.e., a way that would not offend the beggar if he heard you speaking.  Personally, I don't find beggar to be very offensive, but I do think that handicapped persons might take offense at *crippled*.  They might also take offense at *handicapped*.  *homeless person* might be a bit nicer than *beggar* but not all beggars, crippled or not, are in fact homeless so it might not be applicable.  In the end this is *your* diary, if you can't be true to yourself there, where can you be?  Call them by whatever terms you think of them in.

Comment: @Jim - they are what they are.  In almost no circumstance is being a beggar a good thing.  Who would choose to be handicapped?  Who wants to be homeless?

Comment: Perhaps the OP should swap the expression "nicer" with "a less offensive term". There is nothing nice about being forced to beg in the streets.

Comment: @Mari-LouA done

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/crippled, http://thesaurus.com/browse/beggar

Comment: Was the person deliberately maimed by a begging ringleader, or injured from an unrelated accident or illness?

Answer (score 2):

disabled panhandler.  If you have details on how the person was "crippled", it may sound less offensive.  For example, if he/she was is a wheelchair, then:

wheelchair-bound panhandler.

edit: I just realized that you can make it even less offensive by throwing in an adjective of admiration:

a dignified, wheelchair-bound panhandler.

Obviously, you'll want to tailor the adjective of admiration to what you actually perceived - for example, the trait that inspired you to make the donation.

Comment: I think 'mobility impaired' is the new term to focus on what is possible.  You are correct to mention the offensive connotation of 'crippled'

Comment: Impaired/disabled panhandler, like the florida panhandle?

Answer (score 1):

"*Crippled beggar*".

If you say "crippled beggar" but say it in a nice way that's not insulting or patronising, that's fine; both words are accurate, appropriate, standard english. Remember - just because they **have been** used as pejorative terms by other people doesn't mean that they are nasty when **you** use them.

Beware looking for substitute words, you can end up going wrong in various ways:

- Inaccurate: is the person paraplegic, tetraplegic, or an amputee? If you try using medical terms in order to not be offensive, you might simply get them wrong.
- Inaccurate and presumptious: is the person actually homeless? Are they a traveller in any way or do they have a home? All you actually know about them is that they're begging on the street, so don't use a description which assumes you know why.
- Anachronistic: sorry, but neither *pauper* and *asking for alms* are common usage.
- Patronising: somebody who can't use their legs might not be *differently-abled*; they might well be disabled i.e. handicapped, genuinely impaired by their condition. Calling them *differently-abled* might itself be offensive because it implies that their physical condition is not a disability.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, in many instances, *veteran* would be apt. I have seen enough men on street corners holding cardboard signs that say "Homeless vet -- anything will help" and the like. Moreover, reports abound about the plight of veterans being left to fend for themselves. Of course, this is not at all a nice way of saying "crippled beggar." However, qualifying my observation with "in many instances" does not sufficiently indicate that crippled beggars are not always veterans of military service and vice versa.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/03/07/12-startling-statistics-veteran-homelessness_n_1327816.html

Comment: .....so true :/

Comment: While this might be somewhat accurate, I don't think it answers the question. OP is looking to describe this person with precision, from the sounds of things, and to just call them a veteran would be guesswork at best. It may also offend veterans.

Comment: @Mahnax Of course you are correct.I should have made a comment instead of offering an answer. And I would never want to offend veterans, especially not while trying to express sorrow over the way they are so often treated.

Comment: Is *veteran* synonymous with disability and begging?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - no.  This is a terrible answer.  All veterans are not crippled beggars and all (not even remotely close) crippled beggars are veterans.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd It had five upvotes, and I was taken aback. If the poster at least *explained* the instances when this might be acceptable, some of us are not American, then it might be a useful answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it is a scene in a movie.  This works when the guy is specifically a veteran (military).  I am not saying that there are no veterans on the street but that is really offensive to veterans.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested as a comment, consider *differently-abled panhandler*.

Answer (score -1):

*Gimpy indigent; physically-afflicted pauper.*

Comment: *Gimp* is derogatory. I'd stay away from that one.

Comment: @Mahnax - C'mon, dude. There *isn't* a 'nice' way to describe the OP's subject, because their situation isn't a nice one. No amount of pussyfooting PC-speak is going to improve the condition of someone who finds themselves in those circumstances; when we try to dress them up to make them sound more decorous, it's ultimately only for *our* benefit.

Comment: Oh come *on*. I think affording someone the basic respect of not using a derogatory term to refer to them is a standard that is easily upheld. There are better options. Furthermore, OP asked for a *nice* way to refer to a person in such a circumstance, not an explicitly derogatory one.

Comment: @Mahnax - There's a difference between inventing some blackly humorous epithets and actually using them to address people with. I would never describe anybody in those terms to their face. Lighten up!

Comment: We differ here. I will leave it at that.

Comment: I think the point is that gimp is an epithet. There are plenty of words to use that, while not "nice", aren't used solely as insults.

Answer (score -2):

Disabled homeless person, vagabond, hobo… I believe the term would be 'disabled' or 'handicapped'.

Comment: "vagabond" seems to imply that they move from town to town. And I thought hobos are drifters that do odd jobs, not beggars.